# Can an orthogonal matrix have a determinent that is not 1 nor -1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

As above. Proofs, examples and counter-examples are appreciated.

Comment: What did you try to do to solve this problem? I guess the answer is in every single book 
 that deals with orthogonal matrices...

Comment: @Taladris I'm not doing a course or reading a book, it just crossed my mind. I didn't know its classic textbook question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix $O$ satisfies

$O^TO = I; \tag 1$

thus

$\det O^TO = \det I = 1; \tag 2$

but

$\det O^TO = \det O^T \det O, \tag 3$

and

$\det O^T = \det O, \tag 4$

so (2)-(4) yield

$(\det O)^2 = 1, \tag 5$

which forces

$\det O = \pm 1. \tag 6$

Comment: In (2), the product of determinents must be one, but couldn't that be something like 0.5 and 2 ?

Comment: also, it seems to me that you ignored complex values? DFT matrix is orthogonal and its determinent is j or -j or 1 or -1 depending on size

Comment: @JohnDeterious:   in answer to your first question, no, because of (4).  By the way, thanks for the "acceptance".  Cheers!

Comment: @JohnDeterious:  for your second question, orthogonal matrices are defined to be *real*, so the determnant is real. The complex equivalent is the *unitary* matrices, which satisfy $U^\dagger U = (U^T)^\ast U = I$.  A similar argument to the one in my answer shows that $\vert \det U \vert = 1$ or $\det U = e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Just to be safe: You have to be careful, whether you mean **orthogonal** or **orthonormal** matrices.</del>

<del>The former satisfy that all the columns are orthogonal. With resources to the standard scalar product this is the case for $$\begin{bmatrix} 7&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},$$ which has determinant $7$.</del>

Orthogonal matrices have pairwise orthogonal and normalized (length 1) columns. Those matrices can only have determinant $\pm 1$, since their inverse is their transpose, which has the same determinant and they have to multiply to 1.

Comment: Be careful! The terms “orthogonal” and “orthonormal” as you’re using them in the first paragraph apply to **bases** of vectors spaces, not to matrices.

Comment: Thanks alot. I now remember that some very funny guy meant it would be a good idea to switch the meaning of orthogonal with respect to bases or matrices. Will edit.